# ASP.Net HiddenField value not updating when changed on client-side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, hiddenfield

I have a JavaScript function called from code-behind that has both input parameters and a return value. I've found that other people required similar functionality and that they were offered a HiddenField as a possible solution. So, that is exactly what I'm trying to do - using such a control to emulate the function value return behavior.

The problem is that all I get in code-behind once the client clicks a button is the previous value of that particular field. First time it is null, each next time it is either "true" or "false" (as string) depending on what the client has chosen.
Well, I cannot work with previous value, it has to be "real-time".

I've heard people mentioning AJAX as a way to communicate between client and server, but I don't know how to implement that solution.

I will provide additional information upon your request.

Markup (partial):

```
<body id="body">
    <form id="mainForm" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptManager" EnablePageMethods="true">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="/jquery-2.1.0.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="/Dialog.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:HiddenField id="hfData" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function deleteDialog(contact) {
    var response = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the contact ' + contact + '?');
    var hiddenField = $('#hfData')[0]; // fetches the element as expected
    hiddenField.value = response.toString();
    alert(hiddenField.value); // prints correct values
}
```

Code-behind:

```
Address addressDelete = addressService.fetchById(contactDelete.address_id);
string contactFullName = String.Join(" ", contactDelete.first_name, contactDelete.last_name);
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "delete", "deleteDialog('" + contactFullName + "');", true);
Response.Write(hfData.Value); // I've also tried the Request.Form method but to no avail
contactService.delete(contactDelete);
addressService.delete(addressDelete);
```

Comment: when you want to get the hidden field value.in code behind to client or client side to code behind.@Venom

Comment: @SumitPathak There's a Response.Write() call (only for testing purposes) in the code-behind event handler - if I understood your comment correctly.

Comment: What method in your code-behind is this code from?

Comment: @RickS I have a GridView control and a template field situated inside that control that contains a LinkButton whose event-handler is called once it is clicked. Therefore, the method you want to know about is in fact the LinkButton's event-handler.

Comment: You server code has already executed and done the Response.Write before you get the hidden value from the client.  I think you're confused about the flow of ASP.NET pages.

Comment: @RickS Most probably, I am more accustomed to classic, desktop applications. So, when and where should I retrieve the value I need?

Comment: You need to explain the flow of your page.  Step us through what the user is doing and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @RickS It's quite simple, there is a GridView control containing data (BoundFields) and a TemplateField with two LinkButtons - Edit and Delete that have their own event-handlers. The Delete LinkButton's (for example, shown in my question) event-handler internally calls a JavaScript function that raises a dialog and based on the user's choice (true or false return value, or rather, the HiddenField's value) - to delete or not to delete the selected GridView's row (a record in the database). I'm hoping you understand what I mean.

Comment: Make sure you're not resetting the value of the HiddenField upon postback (which would overwrite what you've done on the client side).

Comment: @mason Well, the only thing I'm doing with it is retrieving its value in code-behind after calling the JavaScript function. As I've said it, calling hfData.Value returns the "previous" value, not the expected one.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
function deleteDialog(contact) {
var response = (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the contact ' + contact + '?')) ? true : false;
var hiddenField = $("<%= hfData.ClientID %>").value; // fetches the element as expected
/*hiddenField.value = response.toString();*/
alert(hiddenField); // prints correct values
}
```

Or check :

```
  alert(document.getElementById("<%=hfData.ClientID%>").value);
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything if I modify the function like this. Also, I have to use jQuery's fetching mechanism because the script is external and delegated to a user control (.ascx) from a parent form (.aspx).